# Docker compose always makes a new volume instead of using named ones

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My problem is as the title states.

Here are the steps to reproduce. Note I am using docker compose file version 3.3, as I am running this off the apt python version of docker-compose as there is no binary for ARM64.

Create a docker file with these contents:

```
version: "3.3"

volumes:
  owncloud_data:
    external: true
  owncloud_mysql:
    external: true
  owncloud_backup:
    external: true
  owncloud_redis:
    external: true

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: "always"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
     #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      # Be sure to have LeGo installed
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=<my email>"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"


  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    restart: "always"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`<my domain>`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=myresolver"

  owncloud:
    image: "owncloud/server"
    container_name: "owncloud"
    restart: "always"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=owncloud.<my domain>
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_TYPE=mysql
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_NAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_HOST=db
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_USERNAME=<my username>
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=<my password>
      - OWNCLOUD_MYSQL_UTF8MB4=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_ENABLED=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_HOST=redis
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.owncloud.rule=Host(`<my domain>`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.owncloud.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.owncloud.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: owncloud_data
        target: /owncloud/data

  db:
    image: webhippie/mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MARIADB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=owncloud
      - MARIADB_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=128M
      - MARIADB_INNODB_LOG_FILE_SIZE=64M
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: owncloud_mysql
        target: /owncloud/mysql
      - type: volume
        source: owncloud_backup
        target: /owncloud/backup

  redis:
    image: webhippie/redis:latest
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      - REDIS_DATABASES=1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: owncloud_redis
        target: /owncloud/redis
```

I run this command before I start the containers:

```
for v in owncloud_data owncloud_mysql owncloud_backup owncloud_redis; do
    sudo docker volume create $v
done
```

I then run `sudo docker-compose up`.

When I run `sudo docker volume ls` I get my four (dangling volumes) I created earlier, and 4 more ones that were created from docker compose. What's the deal here? I specified their name explicitly. I'm not sure why the bind for the traefik container works.

I have tried seemingly everything. I put things in quotes. I tried the prepended project name. I tried the short syntax `owncloud_data:/owncloud/data`. I tried binds, although I don't want to use binds since it's easier to backup a volume.

Thank you, Logan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose` is using the volumes you named, **for the binds you specified**. However, it is also creating unnamed volumes for each `VOLUME` declaration on the images you are using and not explicitly binding.

I've made this little script to extract the declared volumes from the images you're using:

```sh
images="traefik containous/whoami owncloud/server webhippie/mariadb:latest webhippie/redis:latest"

echo $images | xargs -n1 docker pull

docker inspect $images -f '{{.RepoTags}}, {{.Config.Volumes}}'
```

The result:

```
[traefik:latest], map[]
[containous/whoami:latest], map[]
[owncloud/server:latest], map[/mnt/data:{}]
[webhippie/mariadb:latest], map[/var/lib/backup:{} /var/lib/mysql:{}]
[webhippie/redis:latest], map[/var/lib/redis:{}]
```

None of your binds are binding to the declared volumes, so you're effectively creating new ones and leaving the declared ones empty.

Comment: How do I go about making the images reference the volumes. I thought that's what the `volume` directive was under the each service was for? If it starts with `.` it's a relative *bind* and if it's just a named *volume* which I created external to the script.

Comment: ~~Using `docker inspect` I can see that both mounts are there, but under config volumes, like your script says, there is no bind to the volume. Would I put `/var/lib/docker/volumes/owncloud_data:/owncloud/data` for volumes under the service? Isn't that considered a bind mount and not a volume?~~ Didn't work.

Comment: So, I think I understand what you are saying. I need to point the volume to the correct directory that the *image specifies* (I was kind of wondering how the image knew where to look). I wonder why the owncloud tutorial I followed said to use `/owncloud/data` instead of `/mnt/data`... Is assume I can configure the image to use that instead. Anyways, it's working now! Thank you.